# Installation of XDEBUG on OSX 10.11

Tags: php, shell, xdebug, osx-elcapitan, pecl

When I'm trying install XDEBUG `sudo pecl install xdebug` - the next error occurred:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so'
ERROR: failed to write /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so 
(copy(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted)
```

Have you got any ideas how to solve that problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably a question for *[super user](http://superuser.com)* ... fwiw you are probably being victimized by the new SIP (rootless) toys shipped by Apple. That broke quite a few installation frameworks (PECL here), i see it tries to target a protected area (/usr/lib). You may want to try *[Homebew](http://brew.sh)* to beef-up your mac, which sticks to `/usr/local` as target destinations. If you do, you will possibly need to install your own php, and figure out how to nuke Apple's brain dead apache and php.

Comment: Look yesterday I've got those conflict with SIP. But now when I'm trying to: @sudo pecl install debug@ the next error: autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/bin/m4
ERROR: `phpize' failed...  And what I should do with that ?